# Is there a way i can store html output inside a variable?

Tags: pyscript

I am trying to store the html result inside a variable but it displays none.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Lively Forest</title>

    <!-- Recommended meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- PyScript CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.12.1/core.css">

    <!-- This script tag bootstraps PyScript -->
    <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.12.1/core.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="py">
        from pyscript import display,HTML
        x = display(HTML("<h1>hello</h1>"))
        display(x)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i store it inside a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = display(HTML("<h1>hello</h1>"))
display(x)
```

You're saving the result of `display()`, but you actually want the result of `HTML()`.

Use this instead:

```
x = HTML("<h1>hello</h1>")
display(x)
```