# How to convert HTML object to str object

Tags: python, pyscript

Generally, `str` objects display on the console. How can I convert my `html` object to an `str` object so that it can display on the console?

```
x = HTML('<p>hello</p>')
string = str(x)
display(string)
```

Comment: try using `html2text`  script ; 

import html2text

html_content = '<p>hello</p>'
text_content = html2text.html2text(html_content)

print(text_content)

Comment: @Sumanjha if you're going to provide full code, please write an answer, not a comment.

Comment: What is `HTML` in this case? (which package are you importing?)

Comment: I am importing from **pyscript import HTML** . @Suman jha your code works for me but displays few blank spaces after display.

Comment: Why do you want to convert your HTML element to a string?

Comment: I am trying to establish a connection between the DOM and terminal. Previously i was using button and now without button just wanted to display my html into terminal.It was not displaying directly ref [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77870688/is-there-a-way-i-can-store-html-output-inside-a-variable/77870700#77870700).Converting html to string will solve the problem.